# Monitor the Garbage Collector of an SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, controller, garbage-collecting

The **SSD** controller triggers the **garbage collection** routines on a specific ship or block when a certain threshold of either invalid pages or written pages is met, based on the GC policy (my guess is that most SSDs use the greedy policy).

I am trying to measure the impact of some workloads on a specific SSD, I've already done the performance measurements using **FIO**, but i would like to go even further.

Is there a way to get notified when the Garbage Collector routine on a SSD is triggered?

Comment: If this is a NVMe SSD the nvme-cli has some extended statistics on usage wear and fill, but not really much on GC http://feed.askmaclean.com/archives/using-nvme-command-line-tools-to-check-nvme-flash-health.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what you are asking is basically the "secret sauce" of your SSD controller firmware. SSD vendors treat the internal controller routines, and their implementation, as a trade secret.

You can only guess at what is happening by triggering a specific load and carefully examine the results.